# Permission errors when trying to build Haxe project

Tags: haxe, permission-denied, openfl, haxeflixel, haxelib

When I try to build my Haxe project in HTML5/JavaScript with the `lime` tools, I get this error, and these warnings:

```
jesse@jesse-kubuntu ~/C/Similar-Game> lime test html5
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/haxelib/lime/2,9,1/templates/bin/webify-linux64’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/haxelib/lime/2,9,1/templates/bin/webify-linux64’: Operation not permitted
Warning: Could not find generated font file "/usr/share/haxelib/flixel/4,0,1/assets/fonts/nokiafc22.eot"
Warning: Could not find generated font file "/usr/share/haxelib/flixel/4,0,1/assets/fonts/nokiafc22.woff"
Warning: Could not find generated font file "/usr/share/haxelib/flixel/4,0,1/assets/fonts/nokiafc22.svg"
Warning: Could not find generated font file "/usr/share/haxelib/flixel/4,0,1/assets/fonts/monsterrat.eot"
Warning: Could not find generated font file "/usr/share/haxelib/flixel/4,0,1/assets/fonts/monsterrat.woff"
Warning: Could not find generated font file "/usr/share/haxelib/flixel/4,0,1/assets/fonts/monsterrat.svg"
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/haxelib/lime/2,9,1/templates/bin/node/node-linux64’: Operation not permitted
sh: 1: /usr/share/haxelib/lime/2,9,1/templates/bin/node/node-linux64: Permission denied
jesse@jesse-kubuntu ~/C/Similar-Game>
```

**How do I resolve these warnings and errors?**  And don't say `sudo`, I shouldn't have to do that to build a game.

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed lime using sudo, so then try this:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/haxelib/lime/2,9,1/templates/bin/webify-linux64
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/haxelib/lime/2,9,1/templates/bin/node/node-linux64
```

This will give 'execution' rights to all users.